# document.getElementsByTagName return value

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to use

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input').concat( some_array )
```

but `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns an `object` instead of `array`

How to get the array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately to do this fully reliably you need to do it manually, eg:

```
function toArray(arraylike) {
    var array= new Array(arraylike.length);
    for (var i= 0, n= arraylike.length; i<n; i++)
        array[i]= arraylike[i];
    return array;
}

toArray(document.getElementsByTagName('img')).concat(...)
```

Whilst you often *can* get away with using `Array.prototype.somearraymethod.call` as in Sean's answer, this may fail on browsers where the `NodeList` object returned by `getElementsByTagName` is a ‘host object’.

ECMAScript defines that calling methods on the `Array.prototype` has to work for native-JS objects with a `length` and integer properties, and for the `arguments` object, but it makes no guarantees for host objects. As with almost everything involving host objects, the browser is free to screw you over however it likes.

Comment: Well, Sean's answer works perfectly in FF, Opera and Chrome. ... But doesn't work in ie6. Can anyone tell me about ie7, ie8, ie9?

Comment: benchmarking says prototype.slice.call() runs much faster than toArray().

Comment: I haven't tested this but I would expect it to work in IE8+ Standards Mode (which uses native objects for the DOM), and fail for IE7. It will also fail on other more obscure browsers.

Comment: @bobince -- off the top of your head, is the error thrown by attempting to call `slice` on a host object catchable? (I'm thinking this function could be sped up by checking if we can use slice -- but I'm pretty sure that such errors are uncatchable.)

Comment: In IE, it's catchable. However of course we are talking about undefined behaviour here, so in general there's no guarantee that you'll get an exception when it doesn't work, or that if it does work once it'll always work!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to support IE versions less than or equal to 7* then use `slice()`:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(
    document.getElementsByTagName('img')).concat(some_array)
```

`*` Thanks bobince!