# Traversing up the DOM tree to display info about the parentNode

Tags: javascript

I feel this should be an easy problem, but alas I find myself stuck. What I'm trying to do is set up a way so that every time you click on a cell on a table(or anywhere), it displays the parentNode of each element, essentially traversing up the DOM tree. I figured I would need to use elem.parentNode, but I'm stuck on the traversing part. Any gurus out there that can help me out, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var element; //your clicked element
while(element.parentNode) {
    //display, log or do what you want with element
    element = element.parentNode;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Quick question though, why use element.parentNode instead of element?

Comment: Each element in DOM has its `parentNode` - excluding root node, which is `Document`. So you iterate over element as long, as element has a `parentNode`. In `while` body you assign current elements `parentNode` to element variable, so it could run on and on until it will reach `Document` which has no `parentNode`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
for (var i=0,len=tables.length;i<len;++i){
  tables[i].onclick = function(evt){
    if (!evt) evt = window.event;
    var element = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    while (element){
      console.log(element);
      element = element.parentNode;
    }
  };
}
```

If you really want clicking on any element everywhere, then simply:

```
document.body.onclick = function(evt){
  if (!evt) evt = window.event;
  var element = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
  while (element){
    console.log(element);
    element = element.parentNode;
  }
};
```

Comment: I thought until today that event properties like `currentTarget` and `target` weren't available in IE. It appears they just have cousins in IE, like with various other properties. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an Object not an Array so'll need to use `Array.prototype.method.call` or [create a fake array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513162/document-getelementsbytagname-return-value) to iterate it correctly.

Comment: @rxgx It actually returns a [`NodeList`](http://objjob.phrogz.net/dom/object/203), which has a `length` property and (per the specs) has items that are accessible via integer indices. As such, looping as I have done is perfectly fine.