# for loop not running more than once

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop

I am making an `<anchor>` element which is meant to clone the `<a>` element. I have two of the `<anchor>` elements in my body but only one has been converted to an `<a>` element! Here is my JavaScript:

```
var t = document.getElementsByTagName("anchor");
for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
  var c = t[i];
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.setAttribute("href", c.getAttribute("href") + "?utm_source=" + window.location.href);
  a.innerHTML = c.innerHTML;
  c.parentElement.append(a);
  c.remove();
}
```

Comment: share your html also

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName()` is a live HTMLCollection, so when you call `c.remove()`, the length of `t` becomes 1. You can circumvent this by caching `t.length`:

```
var tLen = t.length;
for (v i = 0; i < tLen; i++) {
```

Comment: @Xavida, please add your html to your original post so we can give specific advice.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you are trying to use .length to loop though an object, when .length only works on arrays.

getElementsByTagName() [returns a object, not an array](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp)
and [Array.prototype.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) only works on arrays.

I found a other post about getting an array of getElementsByTagName(): [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513162/document-getelementsbytagname-return-value)

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an HTMLCollection, which absolutely has a `length` property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection